# Error when passing the source_server to restore Mysql server

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I hope you are very well, community I have a problem I am trying to restore an Azure Mysql server on a new Azure subscription. For this I am using the command `"az mysql flexible-server restore"`. But there is a field called "source_server" that is giving me problems because it is modifying the path which causes me to generate this error.
ERROR: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
ERROR: The provided source_server C:/Users/denilsonhs/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/subscriptions/76f790a3-75b7-445c-a345-c2c0547e74ce/resourceGroups/ReactivacionComfama/providers/Microsoft.DBforMySQL/flexibleServers/flex-mysql-dev-qa is invalid.

The initial id is: source_server="/subscriptions/$subscriptionorigin/resourceGroups/$RG/providers/Microsoft.DBforMySQL/flexibleServers/$server".

But when I run the file it changes the path to me like this:  C:/Users/denilsonsonsonhs/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/subscriptions/76f790a3-75b7-445c-a345-c2c0547e74ce/resourceGroups/ReactivationComfama/providers/Microsoft.DBforMySQL/flexibleServers/flex-mysql-dev-qa.

Do you know how I can do so that the path is not altered and the file can be executed without problems.
For this I am using GitBash and azure-Cli.
I remain attentive to your answers thanks community!

I have tried putting the ID directly but when I run the restore it changes the address and does not recognize where the server is.

Attached is a sample of the additional code that appears once I launch the code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is mainly with `source-server` parameter. You need to pass the `resourceID` or `resourcename` as an argument to the source server but not the local file path.

```bash
az mysql flexible-server restore --resource-group Databases-Resources --name xxx --source-server "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/<resource group>/providers/Microsoft.DBforMySQL/flexibleServers/<server>" --public-access Enabled
```

***Output:***

[image]

Refer [`az mysql flexible-server restore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/mysql/flexible-server?view=azure-cli-latest#az-mysql-flexible-server-restore) command parameters for better understanding.